# Generate java client libraries using Enunciate

Tags: rest, documentation, enunciate

I have a couple of RESTful webservices i want to document using [Enunciate 1.25](http://enunciate.codehaus.org) using Maven. If i build without the custom enunciate.xml, all the client libraries are built as expected.

```cs
...
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-enunciate-plugin.version}</version>
                <!-- configuration>
                    <configFile>src/main/resources/enunciate.xml</configFile>
                </configuration -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
...
```

As soon as i add my add my custom enunciate.xml, the client library for java is no generated

```cs
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<enunciate label="service/myservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://enunciate.codehaus.org/schemas/enunciate-1.25.xsd">

    <modules>
        <docs splashPackage="myservice.service"
            includeDefaultDownloads="false" disableRestMountpoint="true"
            applyWsdlFilter="false" docsDir="api" title="My Service API"
            copyright="ME Inc" />
        <basic-app disabled="false" />
        <java-client disabled="false" />
        <xml disabled="false" />
        <jaxws-client disabled="false" />
        <jboss disabled="false" />
        <jaxws-ri disabled="true" />
        <jaxws-support disabled="true" />
        <csharp disabled="true" />
        <jersey disabled="true" />
        <c disabled="true" />
        <obj-c disabled="true" />
    </modules>

    <webapp disabled="false" mergeWebXML="../webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml" />

    <namespaces>
        <namespace uri="http://schema.me/services/myservice" id="myservice" />
    </namespaces>

    <services>
        <rest defaultRestSubcontext="/" />
    </services>

    <api-classes>
        <include pattern="myservice.service.*" />
    </api-classes>

</enunciate>
```

What could i have done wrong or missing?

Comment: Do you get any information from outputting debug logging (e.g. "mvn -X"). You might see something like "java-client module is disabled because..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

includeDefaultDownloads="false" should be true